# How to convert base 64 to byte Array?

Tags: arrays, angular, base64, angular11

How to convert base64 to byte Array in angular. I am trying it but it doesn't work.

```
// file upload
 handleUpload(event) {
   if (event.target.files[0]) {
     this.file = event.target.files[0].name;
   }
   const file = event.target.files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = () => {
     // console.log(reader.result);
     this.base64ToArrayBuffer(reader.result);
   };
 }
```

```
  //  base64  to byte array
  base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64)
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    console.log(bytes.buffer)
    this.fileBase64 = bytes.buffer;
    return bytes.buffer;
  }
```

I want to fileBase64  variable to be a byte Array but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 // file upload
  handleUpload(event) {
    if (event.target.files[0]) {
      this.file = event.target.files[0].name;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = this.handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
      }

  base64ToArrayBuffer(readerEvt) {
    var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
    this.base64textString = btoa(binaryString);
  }
```